# Find the 1 standard deviation move of a time-series

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I have a time-series:

```
243.7206226
605.3606113
605.7932288
844.0799284
261.9561457
586.7027651
185.5579002
320.9357321
954.6565384
82.62499004
60.04110858
337.3290087
285.5276859
48.92526861
177.3709222
794.0821386
216.7704222
229.5233922
33.26274964
```

I would like to know based on the time-series, the potential value if the time-series moved by 1 standard deviation.  I've looked at the NORMINV but can't get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, - (minus) please.  If the next value was to experience a 1 s.d. move down, what would the value be please

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, if I understand the question, is to: 
(a) calculate the standard deviations to the side for a given range and then 
(b) compute the potential next value in the row below by subtracting the stdev from the last value that you have.

```
            A              B                  C
Row#   Orig Value        StDev            Potential
1      243.7206226      
2      605.3606113   
3      605.7932288   
...
18     229.5233922
19     33.26274964       =STDEV(A1:A19)
20                                        =A19-B19
```